# Laravel is great but... where's the consideration for HATEOAS?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, hateoas

I've begun using Laravel 5.4 instead of Spring boot for a web application I'm currently developing and it's going great. I'm really enjoying the lack of verbose boilerplate that Java/Spring has. However, one of my requirements is that the API must be HATEOAS.

I've literally searched for days for research material and only come up with a couple of not-so-popular libraries. Is there a reason for this complete lack of exposure of HATEOAS for Laravel when for other web application frameworks there's at least **some** material?

Edit: I'm not trying to talk down on Laravel, I just want to know why there's no resource on HATEOAS implementations with Laravel as the framework, or if I've missed it, where I can read up on some HATEOAS Laravel goodness.

Comment: Have not used it, but looking at google result here is for laravel. https://github.com/jarischaefer/hal-api  for general here is for php http://hateoas-php.org/ and also https://api-platform.com/docs/

Honestly i couldn't get in depth benefit of HATEOAS

Comment: Yeah this is the kind of reading I've been doing, looks as if Laravel doesn't bake in HATEOAS like it does some other useful stuff. Okay thanks!

Comment: yeah Laravel is wonderful, Laravel is completely inspired form Ruby on Rials, as people like ROR too much same way people like Laravel, advantage of Laravel is it is on PHP which is used almost everywhere. Anyway learn it, with PHP7 it is worth a lot. try installing php7 and see the speed. :)

Comment: I'm really really enjoying it. Despite never coding in PHP before (Java/C#/JS background) I've managed to get a simple application up and going with a lot of the cool features, I'm just missing HATEOAS! Hahaha, trying to get Passport properly running at the mo..

Comment: Passport is just awesome :) good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel uses the Symfony underneath, I think this repo would work: https://github.com/willdurand/Hateoas